# Is there a better way to share R code examples and questions?

Tags: discussion

Edit - This post has been totally reworded for clarity (hopefully).

It seems like the number one factor in a good question and getting a good answer is reproducible code.

From past experience with SQL, I seem to remember people using [SQLFiddle](http://www.SQLFiddle.com) to share examples. This was likely because posting your SQL code may require everyone else to slightly alter their syntax for their particular DB environment (SQL Server, Oracle, mySQL, etc). SQLFiddle gave a common ground that eliminated that step.

Even though R doesn't have that problem, I recently ran across [getdatajoy](http://www.getdatajoy.com) and it got me wondering if there are more convenient ways for users on SO to share code and get answers returned.

As others have pointed out, there probably isn't much friction in copying the code, running it, modifying it and re-pasting, but I thought I'd see if anyone had some input.

Comment: Could anyone downvoting please let me know why? Did I post this in the wrong place? Is it a bad idea for some reason? I just saw the tool and thought it might be helpful to share code examples.

Comment: Because you barely asked a coherent question, but then answered it immediately. Why didn't you just make a suggestion or feature request?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user asked a poor question as an excuse to promote getdatajoy.com

Comment: I already tried to delete it. Feel free to flag it for closure. I had no idea there were such things as suggestions or feature requests. Was basically just trying to share something I saw and thought might be helpful to contribute instead of simply coming here to ask questions.

Comment: @Sam - Please look at my question history. I can promise I'm not here to promote anyone's website.

Comment: I'd be glad to delete the whole question if it would let me.

Comment: I apologize for jumping to conclusions, @JohnTarr.

Comment: No worries, I can see how it would look. I just seemed to remember people using SQLFiddle.com to share examples on SQL questions, and thought that this might be a good way to share R examples. I suppose the difference there is that you couldn't just copy their script and run it due to slight DB implementation differences, so SQLFiddle made sense as a common ground. Of course, I didn't think that far ahead when I posted this. I'm sorry. Now, if anyone knows how the whole question can just be deleted so we can all move on, that'd be awesome.

Comment: Edited for clarity, I hope. Sorry for the crap post.

Answer (score 4):

As you've clarified in your question, you're asking if we should include links to getdatajoy.com projects like [this one](https://www.getdatajoy.com/project/55dc93e6f0fa79bb1a42ca7f) in addition to the code that we post in R questions or answers.

Personally, I don't think this is necessary. This wouldn't save any work for folks answering R questions, since they would still need to include the code and output for the benefit of those who are not going to click on links going to "getdatajoy.com". For instance, when answering the question "How do I plot the sine wave in the interval [0, 2pi] in R?" (note: this is not a particularly good question), one would still need to include a full explanation and all the code and relevant output in the answer itself:

======

You can sample the interval [0, 2pi], plotting the sine of each of the samples using the `plot` function:

```
x <- seq(0, 2*pi, length.out=100)
plot(x, sin(x), type="l")
```

[image]

======

I also don't think this would help those reading the answers to R questions. [Good R questions include a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), meaning all that is required to replicate an R answer is copying the dataset from the question and the code from the answer and running it in your R console. Note that many R answers include the output of commands presented (for instance, I included the output of the plot command above), so readers don't need to run anything at all to see the result of the commands.

Finally, I don't think these getdatajoy.com links would be particularly helpful in questions. You would still need to include all the code and data in the question itself, so it won't save any typing. Since folks can copy that code and data directly into an R console, I don't see the point of linking to a web-based console on getdatajoy.com.

Since I don't think these links would help those answering R questions, those reading the answers to R questions, or those asking R questions, I don't think it would be useful to routinely include getdatajoy.com links in questions under the R tag.

Comment: you're correct, I suppose it is just a matter of copying and pasting examples. I just remembered an online SQL tool that was helpful for sharing issues, but I suppose it isn't necessary with R.